# Is there a way to load bash variables dynamically

Tags: bash, environment-variables

In my bash script, I will load two files for my environment variables, it seems like this:

```sh
# file1 is default
OR=/User/onns
DESKTOP_DIR=${OR}/Desktop
```

```sh
# file2 is different for each pc
OR=/User/pc1 
# maybe /User/pc2 in another pc
```

```sh
$ source file1
$ source file2
$ echo $OR
/User/pc1
$ echo $DESKTOP_DIR
/User/onns/Desktop
```

My question is that is there any way to dynamically reload the variables so I don't need to define `DESKTOP_DIR` twice and just replace the `OR`, Tkx.

Comment: `. file1` will set `OR` and `DESKTOP_DIR` in the current shell. The `.` command for bash is similar to the `source` command for csh.

Comment: @JeffHolt I know, but these two command are the same as I know, and this is not what I wanna ask

Comment: No. With the exception of certain, special, built-in variables, all variable values are computed when stored, not when loaded.

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, don't declare `DESKTOP_DIR=${OR}/Desktop` in either `file1` or `file2`, (in fact there is no need for `file1` at all) but only in the script AFTER you source `file2`, e.g.  `. file2; DESKTOP_DIR=${OR}/Desktop; echo $DESKTOP_DIR`. Then you will have the proper `DESKTOP_DIR` for each PC. (note `.` is a synonym for `source`) Also note, the assignment should be `DESKTOP_DIR="$OR/Desktop"` (double-quote, and there isn't a need to guard with `${...}` when the next character is `'/'`. Guarding doesn't hurt, but the double-quotes should be used)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin But what if I have many variables? I use file1 and file2 because I have many variables for more than one bash script, I can not declare them in each script, thx for ur reply BTW.

Comment: That's fine to have more variables and use a `file1`, just don't declare `DESKTOP_DIR` in it. Wait until you source all files and then declare it. That will work fine too. My comment about the need for your `file1` was based on the contents you show in your question. Nothing more. And note as Gordan mentions in his answer, `ALLCAPS` variable names are generally reserved to the shell. Use lowercase (or mixed-case -- if you must)

Answer (score 2):

bash doesn't have dynamically calculated variables (well, except for some special built-in ones like `$RANDOM`).

One option is to use a function instead of a variable. (Note: I recommend using lower- or mixed-case variable names to avoid conflicts with the various all-caps names that have special meanings to the shell and/or other utilities, so I'll be following this convention in my examples. Also, you should double-quote variable references to avoid weird parsing, except in a few situations like the right side of a plain assignment.)

```
# file1 is default
or=/User/onns
desktop_dir() { echo "${or}/Desktop"; }

# file2 is different for each pc
or=/User/pc1
# maybe /User/pc2 in another pc

$ source file1
$ source file2
$ echo "$or"    # Note double-quoting
/User/pc1
$ desktop_dir    # No `echo` here, the function prints the value
/User/onns/Desktop
# You need to use command substitution to *use* the value
$ dosomething with "$(desktop_dir)"
```

Another option is to load the defaults second, and use [the `:-` option](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value) to change the value only if it's not already defined. Note that in this form the defaults must be applied *after* the per-PC overrides (so the two files are switched).

```
# Here file1 is different for each pc
or=/User/pc1
# maybe /User/pc2 in another pc

# ...and file2 contains the defaults
or=${or:-/User/onns}
desktop_dir=${desktop_dir:-${or}/Desktop}

$ source file1
$ source file2
$ echo "$or"
/User/pc1
$ echo "$desktop_dir"
/User/onns/Desktop
```

You could also use [the `:=` option](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#assign_a_default_value) to apply the default value as part of the expansion... in which case you don't need an explicit assignment, just use the `:` pseudo-command to ignore the result:

```
# Again, file2 contains the defaults
: ${or:=/User/onns}
: ${desktop_dir:=${or}/Desktop}
```